# Resolving services for the IoC DI framework using source generation in opposed to System.Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I like the idea of resolving services in the IoC using attributes. I wanted to replace `System.Reflection` with source generation, so it improves startup time.

The code snippet below is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/navtrack/navtrack/blob/main/backend/Navtrack.Library/DI/Bootstrapper.cs).

### #1 System.Reflection

```cs
[Service(typeof(IListenerService), ServiceLifetime.Scoped)]
public class ListenerService : IListenerService
{
    ...
}
```

```cs
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = GetAssemblies();

        List<KeyValuePair<Type, ServiceAttribute>> serviceAttributes = assemblies
            .SelectMany(x => x.DefinedTypes)
            .SelectMany(x =>
                x.GetCustomAttributes<ServiceAttribute>(false)
                    .Select(y => new KeyValuePair<Type, ServiceAttribute>(x, y)))
            .ToList();

        foreach ((Type type, ServiceAttribute serviceAttribute) in serviceAttributes)
        {
            serviceCollection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(serviceAttribute.Type, type,
                serviceAttribute.ServiceLifetime));
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        List<Assembly> assemblies = GetAssemblies(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()).Distinct().ToList();

        return assemblies;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssemblies(Assembly assembly)
    {
        string namespacePrefix = typeof(Bootstrapper).Namespace?.Split(".")[0];
            
        foreach (Assembly referencedAssembly in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
                     .Where(x => x.Name != null && x.Name.StartsWith(namespacePrefix ?? Empty)).Select(Assembly.Load)
                     .SelectMany(GetAssemblies))
        {
            yield return referencedAssembly;
        }

        yield return assembly;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ServiceAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ServiceAttribute(Type type)
    {
        Type = type;
        ServiceLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped;
    }
        
    public ServiceAttribute(Type type, ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime)
    {
        Type = type;
        ServiceLifetime = serviceLifetime;
    }

    public Type Type { get; }
    public ServiceLifetime ServiceLifetime { get; }
}
```

### #2 Source Generation

I made a Class Library called `Enliven.SourceGenerator` and put the following classes:

```cs
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

namespace Enliven.SourceGenerator;

[Generator]
public class ServiceRegistrationGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var serviceTypes = context.Compilation.SyntaxTrees
            .SelectMany(tree => tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes())
            .OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>()
            .Where(classDecl => classDecl.AttributeLists
                .SelectMany(al => al.Attributes)
                .Any(a => a.Name.ToString() == nameof(ServiceAttribute)))
            .ToList();

        if (serviceTypes.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        var code = new StringBuilder();
        code.AppendLine("using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;");
        code.AppendLine("public static class Bootstrapper {");
        code.AppendLine("    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) {");

        foreach (var serviceType in serviceTypes)
        {
            var serviceAttribute = serviceType.AttributeLists
                .SelectMany(al => al.Attributes)
                .First(a => a.Name.ToString() == nameof(ServiceAttribute));

            var serviceTypeName = serviceType.Identifier.Text;
            var serviceLifetime = serviceAttribute.ArgumentList!.Arguments[1].Expression.ToString();

            code.AppendLine($"        serviceCollection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor({serviceAttribute.ArgumentList.Arguments[0].Expression}, typeof({serviceTypeName}), ServiceLifetime.{serviceLifetime}));");
        }

        code.AppendLine("    }");
        code.AppendLine("}");

        context.AddSource("Bootstrapper", SourceText.From(code.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8));
    }

    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Enliven.SourceGenerator;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ServiceAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ServiceAttribute(Type type, ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime)
    {
        Type = type;
        ServiceLifetime = serviceLifetime;
    }

    public Type Type { get; }
    public ServiceLifetime ServiceLifetime { get; }
}
```

### The issue

I referenced the library in the `Enliven.Host` and did the following. The issue is it doesn't find the generated class Bootstrapper. Why?

```cs
using Enliven.Observability;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Development";

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(c => c
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json"))
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        // Configure services
        Bootstrapper.ConfigureServices(services);
    })
    .AddEnlivenLogging()
    .UseConsoleLifetime()
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```